# Spring Security securing absolute URL paths vs generic regex paths

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, rbac

In Spring Security I want to secure two endpoints behind RBAC

1 - `/api/v1/user/bankDetails` - only users with `admin` permissions should be able to call this endpoint

2 - `/api/v1/user/**` - all the other API endpoints (other than `getInfo`) can be accessed by any user with `read` permissions

How can I ensure that Spring adds RBAC for all `/api/v1/user/**` endpoints but for `/api/v1/user/bankDetails`, only `admin` are allowed?

Now when I add this in my WebFlux application like this -

```java
http
.authorizeExchange()
.pathMatchers("/api/v1/user/**").hasAuthority("read")
.authorizeExchange()
.pathMatchers("/api/v1/user/bankDetails").hasAuthority("admin")
```

Spring security only considers the first one so `bankDetails` endpoint is also open to every user with `read` permissions. Is there a way to differentiate between absolute paths and regex paths such that regex paths have the expected secured behaviour as defined in `pathMatchers` but if the absolute path is defined, then its security check should precede the regex one?

Comment: Change the order of configuration, `bankDetails` shoud come first